# nodejs async/promise hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have the following function:

```
const bulkPreprocess = (files) => {

let bulkOps = []

files.map(doc => {
    parse(doc).then(content => {
        const sent = sentiment(content)
        bulkOps.push(sentiment)
        bulkOps.push({anotherobject})
    })
})
  return bulkOps
}
```

Which is called by a main function like so:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    //parses post request with file uploads
    const form = new multiparty.Form()

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, allFiles) => {
        //called more than once
        const files = allFiles['files']
        let processed = bulkPreprocess(files).then(bulk => {
            console.log(bulk.length)  
            addToES(bulk)
        })
    })

    res.json({ success: true })
}
```

My problem is that since bulkPreprocess calls the `parse` function (which is async), I can't get it to wait until all the files are parsed before `addToES` is called. The parse function itself calls another function which is async (which is why I had to make it async).

The whole flow is like this:

`Main -> bulkPreprocess -> (Parse -> parseDoc) -> return value from bulkPre -> addToES`

I tried changing all the functions to async/await, I tried returning a promise inside the `map` function in bulkPreprocess. I tried callbacks. Nothing is working out.

Any advice?

Comment: That's not how `.map()` should be used. In your example that should be `.forEach()` instead. Why is this tagged `async-await` if you're not using them? Why don't you use `Promise.all()`?

Comment: *I tried changing all the functions to async/await, I tried returning a promise inside the map function in bulkPreprocess* - what exactly did you try and what did not work? What is `sentiment`? Is there a reason why `form.parse` is callback-based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return `Promise` from `bulkPreprocess` which resolves after your async `parse` so you need `Promise.all` to wait for all `parse` calls are finished

**Edit:**
Now it's push objects to `bulkOps` and `resolve` with it after all `parse` are finished

```
const bulkPreprocess = (files) => {
    let bulkOps = [];
    return Promise.all(files.map(doc => {
        return parse(doc).then(content => {
            const sent = sentiment(content);
            bulkOps.push(sentiment);
            bulkOps.push({anotherobject});
        });
    })).then(() => bulkOps);
};
```

Comment: The function actually pushes two objects to `bulkOps`. I just took one out in the post for brevity

Comment: This still calls `addToES` more than once

Comment: Impossible, `Promise` can be settled (resolved/rejected) only once

Comment: I think it has something to do with the main function that calls addToES

Comment: @ninesalt This IS posible :)

Comment: Any idea why its happening?

Comment: @ninesalt add context of `form.parse` call

Comment: Added the whole func. Apparently `form.parse` itself is being called more than once

Comment: @ninesalt put `console.log` inside `form.parse` and inside exported function, if everything is doubled it means you call it twice

Comment: This problem is unrelated to the promises thing. You solved my issue, so thank you :)